# How to restore VSC conflict highlighting?

Tags: visual-studio-code, merge-conflict-resolution

So in visual studio code when you merge and have conflicts, visual studio code will highlight the current change in green and the incoming change in blue. However when you have different conflicts in many files, after resolving the first file and I go to the next one, these highlightings don't show up anymore. I still have the HEAD >>>>>> ======= and all that stuff that tells me where the conflicts are but it is not in color and the buttons to "Accept Current"/"Accept Incoming"/"Accept both" are gone as well. Does anyone know how to tell visual studio code to show those highlightings again in the rest of the files?

Answer (score 0):

Go to Settings -> Extensions -> Git

or search for `merge editor`

Deselect `Git: Merge Editor`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

** **Update** **

VS Code just released a fix in v1.71 that restores the old conflict decorators if the `Open Merge Editor` is selected.

https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_71#_merge-editor-improvements

Comment: Actually it is in v1.71.2.